# Python FTPS upload error: 425 Unable to build data connection: Operation not permitted

Tags: python, ftplib, tls1.2

I'm trying to use ftps to send a file to a FTP server. Login and changing directory work:

```
import ftplib
ftps = ftplib.FTP_TLS('host','user','pwd')
ftps.set_pasv(True)
ftps.prot_p()
ftps.cwd('/target_directory')
```

however when I try to upload my file:

```
file = open(file, 'rb')
send_cmd = 'STOR file_name.txt'
ftps.storbinary(send_cmd, file)
file.close()
ftps.quit()
```

I get the following error:

```
File "/script/location/script.py", line 161, in <module>
ftps.storbinary(send_cmd,file)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 772, in storbinary
return self.voidresp()
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 229, in voidresp
resp = self.getresp()
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 222, in getresp
raise error_temp, resp
ftplib.error_temp: 425 Unable to build data connection: Operation not permitted
```

I've read that the 425 response code is often a result of being in active mode, which is why I included `ftps.set_pasv(True)` (although this is True by default).

I've also tried just listing the directory contents using `ftps.retrlines('LIST')` but get essentially the same error. I'm using Python 2.7.10. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any access to the FTP server's logs?  I suspect that it is something on the server end which is causing the "Unable to build data connection" error.  Given the fact that you're using FTPS, it _could_ be something like `vsftpd` or `proftpd` refusing TLS data connections _unless_ the TLS session on the data connection is the same TLS session as used for the control connection.

Answer (score 2):

This is a reported bug in python: https://bugs.python.org/issue19500

You can apply the patch in a new class

```
class Explicit_FTP_TLS(ftplib.FTP_TLS):
    """Explicit FTPS, with shared TLS session"""
    def ntransfercmd(self, cmd, rest=None):
        conn, size = ftplib.FTP.ntransfercmd(self, cmd, rest)
        if self._prot_p:
            conn = self.context.wrap_socket(conn,
                                            server_hostname=self.host,
                                            session=self.sock.session)
        return conn, size
```

Comment: When I use this snippet, my program hangs indefinitely. Alternative is to add timeout parameter to the object creation.

Answer (score 0):

thanks [@pin3da](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8332698/pin3da), finaly I fix the bug, it takes a while to find your answer. But for me, it needs to modify a little bit, like below, hope it could help someone else who are struggling on [this problem](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/63699) (a decade ago problem) like me.

```
import ftplib
import ssl

class ImplicitFTP_TLS(ftplib.FTP_TLS):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._sock = None

    @property
    def sock(self):
        return self._sock

    @sock.setter
    def sock(self, value):
        if value is not None and not isinstance(value, ssl.SSLSocket):
            value = self.context.wrap_socket(value)
        self._sock = value

    def ntransfercmd(self, cmd, rest=None):
        conn, size = ftplib.FTP.ntransfercmd(self, cmd, rest)
        if self._prot_p:
            conn = self.context.wrap_socket(conn,
                                            server_hostname=self.host,
                                            session=self.sock.session)
        return conn, size
```

Demo code

```
ftps = ImplicitFTP_TLS()
ftps.connect(host={your_ftp_host}, port=990, timeout=300)
ftps.login({your_ftp_account},{your_ftp_password})
ftps.prot_p()
# do something
print(ftps.getwelcome())
ftps.close()
```