# Connecting FTP server using ftplib in python

Tags: python-3.x, ftplib

i am trying to connect to an ftp server from a VM using ftplib in python to download a file. All ports are open between the VM and the target ftp server.

But i am receiving the below error while the script executes.

Error message: **ftplib.error_temp: 425 Unable to build data connection: Operation not permitted**

Could someone help me out here. Thanks In Advance!

The code i am using:

```
import ftplib 
from ftplib import FTP
from datetime import datetime
import ssl

ftps = ftplib.FTP_TLS()


print (ftps.connect('40.71.*.*',*****))
print(ftps.login('username','password'))


ftps.prot_p()
cdir=ftps.pwd()
print(cdir)
x=ftps.cwd('/SAP/KERNEL/LINUX/')
print(x)
cdir=ftps.pwd()
print(cdir)
ftps.retrbinary("RETR " + "abc.sar" ,open("C:/Users/test/Documents/" + "abc.sar", 'wb').write)
ftps.close()
```

Comment: Can you use an FTP client program to perform the operation, just to check if it is your program or something else preventing it from working?

Comment: I am able to connect through WinSCP  to the particular FTP server and also able to download the file.

Comment: It seems i am able to connect to the server but not able to download or list teh files.     Below is the O/P before the error msg is generated.                                                                        
220 FTP Server ready.
230 User xyz logged in
/
250 CWD command successful

Comment: Can you inspect the FTP log file on the server to see what message is there for the error?

Comment: no relevant information from the logs. Also just to update , i am using python 3.5.

Comment: 1) If there is no corresponding entry in the FTP server log, are you sure you have connected to the correct server? 2) Have a search for "425 Unable to build data connection: Operation not permitted" and see if any of the results suggest something to you.

Comment: Duplicate, answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33438456/python-ftps-upload-error-425-unable-to-build-data-connection-operation-not-per